# can't click UIButton when it's added to UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

guys, i want to click my uiButton after it's added to UIImageVIew, but it doesn't work.
this is my code :

```
UIButton *btnDetail = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]retain];

btnDetail.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
[btnDetail addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];

[self.imageView addSubview:btnDetail];
```

the button can't click when i add it to UIImageVIew, but if i don't add  it to UIImageView, it works properly.
please somebody help me

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Note:** By default the `UserInteraction` property of `UIImageView` is set to **NO**. This the place where most of us makes mistake.
So the main thing to check in while adding any control to `UIImageView` is to set its `UserInteractionEnabled` property to **YES**.

```
[self.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

So modify your code as below:

```
UIButton *btnDetail = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]retain];

btnDetail.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
[btnDetail addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];

[self.imageView addSubview:btnDetail];
[self.imageView bringSubviewToFront:btnDetail];
[self.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

HAppy Coding...

Comment: i've try your code, but nothing happen, i still cant click it.
for more information : before i add the UIButton, i've been add another UIImage to this UiVIewImage, is there affect.??

Comment: Please check out the new code.. I have implemented it and tested. Its working fine now.. Actualy the userinteraction of imageview is bydefault off so you werent able to click on anything added to it. So I have set its usre interaction as enabled. Now working fine

Comment: thnx guys it works perfectly, i can't believe my mistake is just put [self.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; before i add the subview, sure it won't works,, hha ridiclous,, btw thank you so much guys...

Comment: This thing consumed my 4-5 days, was stuck with such issue

Comment: userInteractionEnabled = NO. help me can click through the UIImageView.

Answer (score 7):

UIImageView has `userInteractionProperty` set to NO by default so it does not handle touches and does not propagate them to its subviews. Try to set it to YES:

```
self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: @Imam Arief W. If this doesn't work then something else is your problem.

Answer (score 3):

hey i had use this code. its working properly

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 100.0, 20.0);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(show) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"ShowView" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[image2 addSubview:button];
[image2 bringSubviewToFront:button];
[image2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone has interaction problem with UIButton in UIImageView do next steps.

1 Create property of UIImageView:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *buttonImageView;
```

2 Than synthesize it:

```
@synthesize buttonImageView = _buttonImageView;
```

3 Create implementation method:

```
- (UIImageView *) buttonImageView {

    _buttonImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    [_buttonImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [_buttonImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [addButton setTitle:@"add button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    addButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 50);
    [addButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [addButton setEnabled:YES];
    [addButton setAlpha:1];
    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addNewImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return _buttonImageView;
}
```

4 For example in viewDidLoad method add subview to your view:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.buttonImageView];
```